# signal handler returns segmentation fault:11

Tags: c, unix, signals

I've registered a handler that print signal number and then call the original function to `SIGINT`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void (*orifunc)(int);

void func(int sig) {
    printf("signal number is %d. \n", sig);
    orifunc(sig);
    return;
}

int main() {
    orifunc = signal(SIGINT, func);
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

But as I run, after `printf` executed, it returned a "Segmentation fault: 11".
Why did this happen?

Since `SIG_DFL` is not a real function. I try to code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void func(int sig) {
    printf("signal number is %d. \n", sig);

    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    raise(sig);
    signal(SIGINT, func);
    return;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, func);
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Then it runs `func` recursive and prints strings on the whole screen. 
How can I run the default handler in my handler correctly?

Comment: what is the value of `orifunc()`?

Comment: I think it will be 'SIG_DFL'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `orifunc()`, you need to check if it's one of the special handler values, because these aren't real functions. So you need to do:

```
if(orifunc != SIG_DFL && orifunc != SIG_IGN && orifunc != SIG_HOLD) {
    orifunc(sig);
}
```

Or you can put back the original handler and re-send it to yourself:

```
void func(int sig) {
    printf("signal number is %d. \n", sig);
    signal(sig, orifunc);
    raise(sig);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is SIG_DFL. But I want the function to kill itself after printf like default. What should I do?

Comment: Isn't SIG_DFL a real funtion to run default?

Comment: Look in `sys/signal.h`: `#define SIG_DFL  (void (*)(int))0`

Comment: What you can do is put back the original signal handler, and then send the signal to yourself again.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried. If there is no `signal(SIGINT, func);`, it runs correctly. But why after adding this code, it goes wrong?

Comment: I mean if the signal is not SIGINT or some to kill. I want my function handle this signal again.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Have you seen my updated question?